# Hierarchical data output from App Engine Datastore to JSON?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a large hierarchical dataset in the App Engine Datastore.  The hierarchy is preserved by storing the data in Entity groups, so that I can pull a whole tree by simply knowing the top element key like so:

`query = db.Query().ancestor(db.get(key))`

The question: How do I now output this data as JSON and preserve the hierarchy?

Google has a utility class called GqlEncoder that add support for datastore query results to simplejson, but it basically flattens the data, destroying the hierarchy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're referring to [this code](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/geochat/json.py?r=55) and the "flattening" you mention is done by lines 51-52:

```
   if isinstance(obj, db.GqlQuery):
      return list(obj)
```

while the rest of the code is fine for your purpose. So, how would you like to represent a GQL query, since you don't what a JS array (Python list) of the objects it contains? It's not clear, besides the entity group (which you're recovering entirely), what gives it hierarchy; is it an issue of "parent"?

Anyway, once that's clarified, copying and editing that file into your own code seems best (it's not designed to let you override just that one tidbit).

Comment: It's an issue of 'parent' and allowing that as the hierarchy.

I could modify the existing library, but I figured I'd check here first to see if there was a library that already supported it.

Comment: @Christian, good thinking, but I don't know of one. I suggest you extract that `list(obj)` use into a separate method so the base class can have unchanged functionality and a subclass can override the method and perform the extra processing you need (I assume you want a nested list-of-lists?) while reusing 99% of the base class's functionality -- such a patch might be accepted into the open source parts of app engine, and then you wouldn't have to maintain it yourself in the future.